# How to map HTML markup with plain text equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some `HTML` markup that I am displaying with `TinyMCE`. As an example, the following markup:

```
<p>This is a <b>market</b>.</p>
```

renders as "This is a **market**."

I need to highlight certain specific words whose position etc. is given to me based on the plain text version of the markup. Since the highlighting has to be done in `HTML` (`TinyMCE`), I need to find a way to map the plain text back to the HTML markup.
In the above sample, the first "T" in the sentence would be at position 3 in HTML markup and at position 0 in plain text.

My question(s):
1. How do I go about doing this?

I already tried a brute-force approach, i.e., running through the HTML text and wherever the tag ends, start mapping the html markup position to the plain text. The presence of newlines etc. does seem to trip it up.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: you can get the textContent of an element to get the text without html tags.

Comment: @dandavis: what about the position?

Comment: elm.textContent.indexOf(str) SHOULD be the same as strHTML.indexOf(str)

Comment: also, if whitespacing is a problem, apply white-space:pre to the element or a clone of the element before you look at the textContent.